# Will Swift 3 break dynamic frameworks integrated with Carthage?

Tags: swift, swift3, carthage, bridging-header

So soon Apple will release Swift third iteration, which is both very exciting and terrifying.

I saw that it wouldn't be backward compatible with previous versions, and from going through the [Swift evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution) repo, I understood that it would break because of syntax changes like i++ not supported, or modifying parameters of a function etc..

But, this is very easy to adopt, what I'm more afraid of is that the project management would not compile (exit code 1). Like using dynamic frameworks integrated with Carthage, target specific build parameters, or using objc libraries with bridging headers.

Does anyone know if Swift 3 will complain about Carthage frameworks apart from outdated syntax in them? Or all other points stated in the paragraph above?

Comment: I think that maintainers of said frameworks will have to accommodate for the Swift 3 changes.  For example, step up the major version of the library and update for new Swift syntax.  Then users of the framework can simply specify version requirements in their dependency file, if they still need Swift 2 then stay with older version of library, if they already migrated to Swift 3 specify that no-lower-than version of library is needed.  That's it.  No worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Now that the Xcode 8 GM version released, I was able to began migrating my project, and while the toughest part was the third party libraries built with Carthage, it wasn't as bad as I once thought (most of the libraries already have swift 3 support, and if not, you can always fork, convert to modern syntax and use that, just don't forget to create a PR).

Now my project is up and running in Swift 3, ready for the final release :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will break. There have been fundamental changes made to the clang-importer, the component of the compiler responsible for translating Objective-C to Swift. Meaning that the bridging headers have been changed. Also, Objective-C has changed in fundamental ways. I don't think it will be as straightforward as how you describe it, however.

src: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md